# Incorrect CSS Button Height computing

Tags: css, image, button, height, integrated

I created an example showing the current issue I have with styling a button that contains an image:

[Example](http://image-upload.de/image/0mYKPb/1e310184f3.png) *(sorry, I am not allowed to post images yet)*

The height of the image (`img`) is 32 pixels, but the height of the surrounding `button` is 34 pixels and the height of the surrounding `div` is 36 pixels.

Where do the additional pixels come from?! I want these buttons to have a height of 32 pixels and get rid of the space in between the 2 buttons. I do **not** want to set a specific height for the buttons (e.g. 32px). They should adapt to the size of their content (image, text).

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                border: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            button {
                border: 0; 
                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button><img src="img/site/buttons/32x32/add_user.png"> Benutzer hinzufügen</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button><img src="img/site/buttons/32x32/add_user.png"> Benutzer hinzufügen</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried zeroing out the margins for the img tag?

Comment: And are these all the rules being applied to your elements, or is there another set of style rules somewhere?

Comment: make sure to set margins and paddings to zero, more simply just set `* { box-sizing: border-box }`

Comment: That is the code that results in the linked screenshot (browser Safari). A `margin: 0` for `img` does not change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra space comes from the vertical-alignment of the image.

The initial alignment of the image is `baseline`. There is extra space allowed below the text in order for characters which go below the baseline (g, j, q, etc.) and underline. So aligning the image to the baseline of the text leaves some extra space beneath.

Try this:

```
img { 
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrj8U/)

Comment: Could you explain why this happens? It's quite weird that the alignment changes the space allocated, isn't it?

Comment: @Marcel I've updated my answer with an explanation. Basically extra space is reserved for letters to go below the baseline.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer :)